# Django Q find user by username, first_name and/or last_name

Tags: python, django, logic

I want to find a user based on the fields `username`, `first_name` and `last_name` in the DB.

What I do have so far is:

```
def _build_q_for_field(fieldname, wordlist):
    def _param(x):
        return {fieldname + '__icontains': x}
    return reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**_param(w)) for w in wordlist))

query_string = "Fabian M"
query_words = query_string.strip().split(' ')  # ['Fabian', 'M']

qs = User.objects.all()
qs = qs.filter(
    _build_q_for_field('username', query_words) |
    _build_q_for_field('first_name', query_words) |
    _build_q_for_field('last_name', query_words)
)
```

Assume that we have the following very simple userset:

- User 1: `first_name = 'Fabian'`, `last_name = 'Mueller'`, `username = 'fmueller'`
- User 2: `first_name = 'Fabian'`, `last_name = 'Schulze'`, `username = 'fschulze'`

The code above would return both objects, because all conditions are connected via OR and both users do have `first_name = 'Fabian'`. But I want to have only the user Fabian Mueller in the result set, because the second word in the word list (`M`) is not contained in the second result.

Do you have a clever idea how to archive this? Combining the Q's in the filter method using AND instead of OR does work in the example above, but has serious problems if the word list contains only a single word and would immediately exclude results where the username does not match in such a nice fashion as in the example above.

Do you have a clever solution how to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved if an additional field `full_name` is introduced in the query. It seems necessary to do so, because otherwise all combinations of fields and words in the query have to be considered. The possible combinations quickly explode.

Unfortunately Django < 1.8 needs an "raw" SQL statement (and thus this depends on the database in the backend), whereas Django 1.8 allows to abstract the problem by providing the `django.db.models.functions.Concat` and `queryset.annotate()`.

```
query_db_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username']

if DJANGO_VERSION >= '1.8.0':
    from django.db.models.functions import Concat

    qs = qs\
         .annotate(full_name=Concat(*query_db_fields))\
         .filter(reduce(operator.and_, [Q(full_name__icontains=w) for w in query_words]))
else:
     # (DEPRECATED) Remove this part when support for Django < 1.8 is being dropped
    for w in query_words:
        qs = qs.extra(
             where=['lower(concat({fields:})) LIKE lower(%s)'.format(fields=','.join(query_db_fields))],
                    params=['%{}%'.format(w)]
        )
```